# How to pass a range of values from google sheet to a custom webform link as query string if the range varies?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I have a sheet where I've have hyperlinks to my custom webform. When clicked on a hyperlink it passes the adjacent cell values(Order Number, Client Name, Products) as query string to the webform URL.

You see the problem arises when I try to pass the range of values under "Products". Right now I'm having to pass the arguments manually as the number of products may vary with clients, as you can see below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12xYAT6pkvfeFuQo3lsjPUzbuqvasutXVQ6NqzWwEvE8/edit#gid=1878642243) to a sample sheet

Following is my sample code-

1. `Code.gs`

```js
function doGet(e){
  const tmpl = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form');
  
  tmpl.orderno = e.parameter.orderno;
  tmpl.clientname = e.parameter.client; 
  tmpl.productsHtmlString = getProductsHtmlString(e.parameter.products.split(","));

  return tmpl.evaluate();
}

function getProductsHtmlString(arr){
  const productsHtmlArray = [];

  for(let i in arr){
    productsHtmlArray.push(`<div class="productrow"><input id="product${Number(i)+1}" type="text" class="validate" disabled value="${arr[i]}"><label for="product${Number(i)+1}" class="active">Product</label></div>`);
  }

  return productsHtmlArray.join("");
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

2. `form.html`

```html
<head>
  <?!= include('stylesheet'); ?>
</head>
<body>
    
  <div class="row">
    <input id="orderno" type="text" disabled value="<?= orderno; ?>" class="validate">
    <label for="orderno" class="active">Order Number</label>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input id="clientname" type="text" disabled value="<?= clientname; ?>" class="validate">
    <label for="clientname" class="active">Client Name</label>
  </div>

  <div id="orderdetails">
    Product Details
    <?!= productsHtmlString; ?>
  </div>
</body>
```

3. `stylesheet.html`

```html
<style>
  .row{
    margin-top: 7.5px;
    margin-bottom: 7.5px;
  }
</style>
```

Note: Updated the question to properly reflect my query.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Now my question is, how to dynamically pass a range of values in this case, the "Products" as query string to the webform URL as an array?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike Hi Tanaike, apologies for incorrectly posing my question. I've updated it now. Does it help ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that your issue has been resolved. I'm glad about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solution works for me. The changes I made-

1. In the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12xYAT6pkvfeFuQo3lsjPUzbuqvasutXVQ6NqzWwEvE8/edit#gid=1878642243), I updated *Hyperlink* to have only `rowindex="&row($B2:$B)&"` as `query` string to the URL. This gives me the `index` of the row, which I use it in `getRange()` to fetch the `orderno`, `client` and `products`.
2. In the `doGet()` function in `Code.gs`, I made the following changes-

`Code.gs`

```js
function doGet(e){
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form');

  const rowIndex = Number(e.parameter.rowindex);

  template.orderno = ws.getRange(rowIndex, 2).getValue();
  template.clientname = ws.getRange(rowIndex, 3).getValue();
  
  const productsArr = ws.getRange(rowIndex, 4, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
                      .filter(arg => arg !== '');

  template.productsHtmlString = getProductsHtmlString(productsArr);

  return template.evaluate();
}
```